# Single query per pagination? datatable.js laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Currently I have a table called `tblOrders`

with the query like this

```
 public function getIndex()
 {

    $cart = Cart::orderby('cart_date','DESC')
    ->orderby('cart_no','DESC')
    ->select('id','cart_no','client_id','cart_title')->limit(1000)->get();

    return View::make('_admin.orders.orders', compact('cart'));

 }
```

on my blade file I have this `datatable.js`

```
  <table id="table-order" class="parennt-table uk-table-hover">
  <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>id</th>
             <th>cart_no</th>
             <th>cart_title</th>
             <th>cart_date</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
       @if(count($orderData))
       @foreach ($orderData as $field)
       <tr>
          <td>{{ $field->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $field->cart_no }}</td>
          <td>{{ $field->cart_title }}</td>
          <td>{{ date('M j, Y',strtotime($field->cart_date)) }}</td>
       </tr>

       @endforeach
       @endif

  </tbody>
```

and my js like this

```
  <script>
    oTable = $('#table-order').DataTable({
     "order": [[ 0, 'desc' ]]
   });
  </script>
```

This datatable loads 8k rows. but needed to limit it by 1000 rows

How can I load only 20 rows per page? and query the next 1 when user tries to click specific pagination

Comment: data table can load 20 each per request, https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html you just need to follow how datatables query each page and use the variables, and adjust the php endpoint accordingly since you're using laravel

Comment: you can use laravel paginate `https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination` but you need to link laravel paginate with datatable.js paginate it isn't hard.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination), the first parameter passed to the paginate() function is the number of results returned.

```
 public function getIndex()
 {

    $cart = Cart::orderby('cart_date','DESC')
    ->orderby('cart_no','DESC')
    ->select('id','cart_no','client_id','cart_title')
    ->paginate(50);

    return View::make('_admin.orders.orders', compact('cart'));

 }
```

However, I don't suggest you to use such a high number as 1000 but use more reasonable numbers to reduce the page loading and rendering time.

Anyway, using DataTables I suggest you to install this package [yajra/laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)